# Docker error (Could not build wheels for Pandas which use PEP 517 and connot be installed directly)

Tags: python, pandas, docker

First of all, my environment is

```
[python ver = 3.8]
[django = 3.1.6]
[pandas = 1.1.3 or (1.2.1) use anything]
```

and I use pycharm, venv

I want to make my prj to docker-compose build

ERROR: Failed building wheel for pandas

```
Failed to build pandas
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pandas which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

So, I go to pandas guide and I see:

```
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/contributing.html?highlight=head
```

It says:

```
python -m venv $env:USERPROFILE\virtualenvs\pandas-dev

# Activate the virtualenv. Use activate.bat for cmd.exe
~\virtualenvs\pandas-dev\Scripts\Activate.ps1

# Install the build dependencies
python -m pip install -r requirements-dev.txt

# Build and install pandas
python setup.py build_ext -j 4
python -m pip install -e . --no-build-isolation --no-use-pep517
```

It looks good but I don't know how to apply to my project, because I always use pip in venv only.

```
python -m pip install -e . --no-build-isolation --no-use-pep517
```

How can I use it?

Answer (score 0):

What base image are you using? Try explicitly defining a more recent version of python, if it works with your project. E.g.,

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
```